# SELECT fieldnames FROM dynamic SQL query

Tags: sql, t-sql, crystal-reports

I have a stored procedure that uses several parameters to build a dynamic query, which I execute. The query works fine, however, this procedure will be the data source for a Crystal Report which needs a "static" `SELECT with field names` it can reference. The Crystal Report is called from a Visual Basic application, and gets it's parameters passed to it from the application. It, in turn, passes the parameters to the SQL Server stored procedure.

Somehow I need to

```
SELECT fieldname1, fieldname2 
FROM Exec(@MydynamcSQL)
```

after I build `@MydynamcSQL`. It is a complicated application accessing specific tables based on year, and specific databases based on the user. I am pretty new to SQL, so maybe there are other methods I could use that I am unaware of?

Comment: What type of database are you using?  Microsoft SQL Server?  And what version (year)?  If you add a more specific tag, it will help answer the question, as this type of SQL is very dependent on the type of database.

Comment: @Chipmonkey I think this is T-SQL, PL/SQL has a different syntax for dynamic sql.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a temporary table to insert the data temporarily, then select from that table:

```
DECLARE @MydynamcSQL varchar(1000);

SET @MydynamcSQL = 'select fieldname1, fieldname1 from table1';

CREATE TABLE #Result
(
  fieldname1 varchar(1000),
  fieldname2 varchar(1000)  
)
INSERT #Result Exec(@MydynamcSQL)
SELECT fieldname1, fieldname1 -- here you have "static SELECT with field names"
FROM #Result 
DROP TABLE #Result
```

Comment: I'm thinking this route may be my only option.  I will try this and see how it works with Crystal.

Comment: I was working on reports for some time i think i know your problem, usually those kind of problems in reporting can be solved with temp tables. It is a rough edge solution, if i think of something different i will let you know.

Comment: If I have several users running this report at the same time, will SQL Server make unique versions of the temp table for each user?

Comment: Yes they are created and deleted within a batch or a procedure, in theory there is no need for DROP TABLE #Result.

Comment: Even if every user creates a temp table with the same name it will be specific to a user.

Comment: This appears to be working for me.  I was able to map the stored procedure to the query I based the report on, and (because the fields are named and defined exactly as they are in the query) Crystal allowed the new mapping.  Thanks to all for the replys.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try making the who thing dynamic, such as:

```
Exec( 'SELECT fieldname1, fieldname2 FROM ' + @MydynamcSQL)
```

It's worth noting although out of scope, ensure you are not vulnarable to sql injection attacks. A parameterized dynamic query potentially leaves you exposed.

Comment: My problem is with the dynamic part.  Crystal Reports does not see any data fields when I attach the stored procedure, so I have nothing I can build a report with.  As to the sql injection, my [desktop] app will be passing the parameters which I will build.  the app will have a small, internal user base.