# Getting dynamic query select fields to show in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, crystal-reports, sql-server-2008-r2

I have what I consider to be a pretty complicated query (at least to me) and I decided to attempt to solve it using dynamic SQL. However I have two issues that I have not been able to solve.

**Situation**

In a table, a user can enter an item which has an amount, week and status.

So the data is supposed to resembles this format.

```
            Week 1        Week 2    
---------+-----------+-------------
Status 1 |    50            25
Status 2      10            20
```

And this is the data in SQL.

```
Status 1  | Week 1 | 25
Status 1  | Week 1 | 25
Status 1  | Week 2 | 25
Status 2  | Week 1 |  2
Status 2  | Week 1 |  8
Status 2  | Week 1 | 10
Status 2  | Week 1 | 10
```

For each status I sum the amount based on weeks using a dynamic pivot table.

What have I attempted:

```
--EXEC usp_weekReport @weeks=1, @year='2019'
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_weekReport
    (@weeks INT,
     @year NVARCHAR(4))
AS
    DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @columns = N'';

    SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME([week])
    FROM 
        (SELECT p.[week] 
         FROM [dbo].[Invoices] P
         WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, P.date) = @year
           AND ([week] IN (@weeks)
                OR [week] IN (@weeks + 1)
                OR [week] IN (@weeks + 2)
                OR [week] IN (@weeks + 3)
                OR [week] IN (@weeks + 4)
                OR [week] IN (@weeks + 5))
         GROUP BY P.[week]) AS x;

SET @sql = N'
SELECT p.[statusName],' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    SUM(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(A.amount,'','',''''),''$'','''') AS FLOAT)) as sumInvoice,
  A.invoiceStatusID_FK,
  B.statusName,
  [week]
  FROM [dbo].[Invoices] A
  INNER JOIN invoiceStatus B
  ON A.invoiceStatusID_FK=B.invoiceStatusID
 GROUP BY invoiceStatusID_FK,B.statusName,[week]--,C.programme
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  SUM(sumInvoice) FOR [week] IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p;';
--PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;


CREATE TABLE #reportResult
(
statusName nvarchar(50),
weekA INT DEFAULT 0,
weekB int DEFAULT 0
--weekC int DEFAULT 0,
--weekD int DEFAULT 0,
--weekE int DEFAULT 0,
--weekF int DEFAULT 0
)
INSERT #reportResult Exec(@sql)
SELECT statusName, weekA,weekB--,weekC,weekD,weekE,weekF -- here you have "static SELECT with field names"
FROM #reportResult 
DROP TABLE #reportResult
```

To solve this, I have the above code and while it works(returns the values in SQL)  I have two issues.

**Problems**

My first problem is that, I cannot use this code in conjunction with creating a report in Crystal Reports. When I import the stored procedure, the columns shows up blank. I looked at the following link. [Select field Names from Dynamic SQL query][1]

[1]: [SELECT fieldnames FROM dynamic SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252281/select-fieldnames-from-dynamic-sql-query) and even if I attempted to model my answer after what was said to work exactly. It does not seem to work for me as my data columns are still blank in Crystal.

I had the idea of calling my first stored procedure from a separate stored procedure but given of how my answer is returned (not just a single value that I can assign to a variable, currently thinking of returning a table value function) I doubt that that would work.

A second problem that developed is because my 'weeks' are dynamic (up to 6 weeks) I cant create the temp table with "Spare" columns or I get an error (incorrect number of columns), as you see i commented them out and I also can't use "Select into"

Appreciate any assistance or ideas offered.

Answer (score 0):

Try following, it uses Global TEMP table:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  usp_weekReport 
    @weeks INT,
    @year  NVARCHAR(4)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @columns = N'';

    SELECT @columns+=N', p.'+QUOTENAME([week])
     FROM (
          SELECT p.[week]
          FROM [dbo].[Invoices] P
          WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, P.date) = @year
                AND ([week] IN(@weeks)
                OR [week] IN(@weeks + 1)
                OR [week] IN(@weeks + 2)
                OR [week] IN(@weeks + 3)
                OR [week] IN(@weeks + 4)
                OR [week] IN(@weeks + 5))
          GROUP BY P.[week]
       ) AS x;
     SET @sql = N'
                SELECT p.[statusName],'+STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '')+'
                into ##reportResult
                FROM
                (
                  SELECT 
                    SUM(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(A.amount,'','',''''),''$'','''') AS FLOAT)) as sumInvoice,
                  A.invoiceStatusID_FK,
                  B.statusName,
                  [week]
                  FROM [dbo].[Invoices] A
                  INNER JOIN invoiceStatus B
                  ON A.invoiceStatusID_FK=B.invoiceStatusID
                 GROUP BY invoiceStatusID_FK,B.statusName,[week]--,C.programme
                ) AS j
                PIVOT
                (
                  SUM(sumInvoice) FOR [week] IN ('+STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')+')
                ) AS p;';
 EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
     SELECT *
     FROM ##reportResult;

     IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##reportResult') IS NOT NULL
     BEGIN
      DROP TABLE ##reportResult;
     END;
END
```

Here is a solution without the Global temp table:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  usp_weekReport 
    @weeks INT,
    @year  NVARCHAR(4)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @COLCOUNT int, @TableColumns  NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @columns = N'';

    SELECT @columns+=N', p.'+QUOTENAME([week])
     FROM (
          SELECT p.[week]
          FROM [dbo].[Invoices] P
          WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, P.date) = @year
                AND ([week] IN(@weeks)
                OR [week] IN(@weeks + 1)
                OR [week] IN(@weeks + 2)
                OR [week] IN(@weeks + 3)
                OR [week] IN(@weeks + 4)
                OR [week] IN(@weeks + 5))
          GROUP BY P.[week]
       ) AS x;

    SELECT @COLCOUNT = count(*)
     FROM (
          SELECT p.[week]
          FROM [dbo].[Invoices] P
          WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, P.date) = @year
                AND ([week] IN(@weeks)
                OR [week] IN(@weeks + 1)
                OR [week] IN(@weeks + 2)
                OR [week] IN(@weeks + 3)
                OR [week] IN(@weeks + 4)
                OR [week] IN(@weeks + 5))
          GROUP BY P.[week]
       ) AS x;


      SELECT @TableColumns = CASE When @COLCOUNT = 1 THEN 'weekA'
                            When @COLCOUNT = 2 THEN 'weekA, weekB'
                            When @COLCOUNT = 3 THEN 'weekA, weekB, weekC'
                            When @COLCOUNT = 4 THEN 'weekA, weekB, weekC, weekD'
                            When @COLCOUNT = 5 THEN 'weekA, weekB, weekC, weekD, weekE'
                            When @COLCOUNT = 6 THEN 'weekA, weekB, weekC, weekD, weekE, weekF'                          
                        end;



      CREATE TABLE #reportResult
       (
          statusName nvarchar(50),
          weekA INT DEFAULT 0,
          weekB int DEFAULT 0,
          weekC int DEFAULT 0,
          weekD int DEFAULT 0,
          weekE int DEFAULT 0,
          weekF int DEFAULT 0
       )


     SET @sql = N'
             INSERT INTO #reportResult (statusName,' + @TableColumns +  ')
                SELECT p.[statusName],'+STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '')+'
                into ##reportResult
                FROM
                (
                  SELECT 
                    SUM(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(A.amount,'','',''''),''$'','''') AS FLOAT)) as sumInvoice,
                  A.invoiceStatusID_FK,
                  B.statusName,
                  [week]
                  FROM [dbo].[Invoices] A
                  INNER JOIN invoiceStatus B
                  ON A.invoiceStatusID_FK=B.invoiceStatusID
                 GROUP BY invoiceStatusID_FK,B.statusName,[week]--,C.programme
                ) AS j
                PIVOT
                (
                  SUM(sumInvoice) FOR [week] IN ('+STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')+')
                ) AS p;';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

     SELECT *
     FROM #reportResult;

     IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#reportResult') IS NOT NULL
     BEGIN
      DROP TABLE #reportResult;
     END;
END
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause an error if two people call this ? because of the temp table?